# How to say "Take this but return it to its place"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

At my home everybody like to take my pencils. They are in a little box so everybody can take them.
The problem is that they don't return it to the box when they finish using them. I want to write on a paper a message saying "You can take this but return it to its place".

How can I say it in German?

Comment: [Wiedersehen macht Freude](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~Wiedersehen%20macht%20Freude!&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou)

Comment: @Em1 Beat my by seconds! Or shorter: *WMF*

Comment: »Da steht *auf Wiedersehen* drauf!«

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ihr könnt euch gerne einen (Stift) nehmen, aber legt ihn bitte wieder zurück an seinen Platz" would be a nice message.

"Bedient euch, aber bringt mir die Stifte bitte wieder!" would be shorter and less formal.

Answer (score 0):

> Du kannst dir einen nehmen, aber bring ihn wieder zurück!

or if the pencil wrote the message :)

> Du kannst mich ausleihen, aber bitte bring mich wieder hier her zurück.